# Recoding an arbitrary grouping variable or factor in R

Tags: r, recode

Suppose I have a vector or column of arbitrary length representing some grouping/factor variable with an arbitrary number of groups and arbitrary values for same along the lines of this:

```
a <- c(2,2,2,2,2,7,7,7,7,10,10,10,10,10)
a
[1] 2  2  2  2  2  7  7  7  7 10 10 10 10 10
```

How would I most easily turn that into this:

```
a
[1] 1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  3  3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a <- c(2,2,2,2,2,7,7,7,7,10,10,10,10,10)
c(factor(a))
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3
```

Explanation:

A factor is just an integer vector with `levels` attribute and a class attribute. `c` removes attributes as a side effect. You could use `as.numeric` or `as.integer` instead of `c` with similar or the same results, respectively.

Comment: Huh. Ok, that's interesting. If I just try `factor(a)` I get the original values, plus `Levels: 2 7 10`. So I would not have thought that `c()` would have done anything more than recapitulate my original values. Can you explain why this works as it does? Thanks.

Comment: This is a side effect of `c()`. Think it would be more appropriate to think in terms of `as.numeric(factor(a))`

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen oh, cool! I did not realize as.numeric would do that. I am mystified as to where this "side effect" of `c()` is documented (it's not in c or factor). Thanks both.

Comment: From `help("c")`: "c is sometimes used for its side effect of removing attributes except names"

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen -- +1, and `as.integer(factor(a))` might be even better.